# SO Jobs tooltip bug

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs, tooltips

I've found another [tooltip](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/284804/chat-conversations-tab-tooltip-text-bug) bug.

Sometimes on SO Jobs you see the previous or next job listing link, and the names of the job and employer are too long to list, so they're shortened with ellipsis (`...`), however when you hover it only gives the expanded version of the job title (not the employer), the employer is completely left out of the tooltip, but the "at" is left in.

[image: Tooltip bug]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good catch, @EBrown! Thank you for your report. This should be fixed now.